# Problema ao obter informações do serviço cognitivo Azure(OCR)

Tags: c#, microsoft-azure, windows-service, ocr

Estou desenvolvendo um windows service que baixa uma imagem web, "flipa" ela horizontalmente e envia para o serviço cognitivo do Azure(OCR), a ideia é captar os textos dessa imagem. Porém, quando envio a imagem via requisição o retorno é vazio.

Já testei o mesmo método com imagens diferentes e funcionou normalmente.

Já testei também, via o teste online do azure(https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) que também funcionou normalmente (com ambas imagens).

```
public void FlipaImagem(string url)
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        using (var imgStream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url)))
        {
            using (var objImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgStream))
            {
               objImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);
                if (File.Exists("arquivoFlipado.jpeg"))
                    File.Delete("arquivoFlipado.jpeg");
                objImage.Save("arquivoFlipado.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                objImage.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O método acima salva a imagem "flipada", se eu pegar essa imagem salva e enviar via teste online (que mencionei acima), ele funciona.

Abaixo como estou enviando para o Azure(Lembrando que se eu passar URL de outras imagens funciona normalmente):

```
public RespostaAzure PostServicoAsync(string urlImagem)
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionkey);
        FlipaImagem(urlImagem);
        var imagem = Image.FromFile(@"arquivoFlipado.jpeg");

        ImageConverter _imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] xByte = (byte[])_imageConverter.ConvertTo(imagem, typeof(byte[]));

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(xByte);



        var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);

        streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        queryString["language"] = "pt";
        queryString["detectOrientation "] = "true";
        var novo = urlAzure + queryString;

        try
        {
            var response = httpClient.PostAsync(novo, streamContent).Result;

            var x = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RespostaAzure>(x);


             return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            _imageConverter = null;
            xByte = null;
            imagem.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Obrigado.

===================UPDATE===================

Ao testar diretamente da API(https://brazilsouth.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc/console), percebi que apresenta o mesmo comportamento, sem sucesso ao reconhecer imagens "fáceis de analisar", porém no site do Azure funciona perfeitamente.

Ps: No azure ele diz estar usando a API 2.0 porém quando a uso, tem o mesmo comportamento da 1.0, e ao verificar via console vi que o site do Azure manda a requisição pra uma URL totalmente diferente que acredito estar restrita apenas para eles.

Talvez fique mais claro se eu deixar uma imagem que estou tentando ler e ocorre o problema, junto com os links:

- Link do Azure(Aqui retorna os textos corretamente): 
  https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/
- Link da API(Não retorna os textos):
  https://brazilsouth.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc/console
- Imagem de exemplo:https://www.grupoescolar.com/a/b/o-que-e-um-texto-D5.jpg

Comment: Não entendi, se você envia uma imagem flipada pelo seu código no sandbox ele faz o trace do OCR?

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer sobre "trace", mas quando envio a imagem retorna 200 do azure, mas a resposta vem desta forma: {"language":"pt","orientation":"NotDetected","textAngle":0.0,"regions":[]}

No regions vem vazio, que seria o texto. Porém quando pego essa mesma imagem e testo pelo site do azure funciona normalmente.

Comment: a mesma imagem gerada pelo código apresentado?

Comment: Sim, eu estou salvando a imagem antes de enviar via POST, se eu pegar a imagem que estou salvando e colocar no Azure ela é lida perfeitamente. E mais estranho que isso é que eu se eu pegar uma imagem da web (diferente das que eu preciso) funciona.

Comment: Então o seu erro está em outro lugar, não no script que você postou

Comment: Desculpe, sou novo aqui, não sei se me expressei de certa forma. Mas o script que postei era para apresentar a forma como estou salvando a imagem que está sendo testada. Mas resumidamente a dúvida é como uma imagem pode estar apresentando resultado online mas não via requisição, entende? E eu testei o método de envio com outras imagens e funcionou normalmente, passando a URL de ambas.

Comment: Justamente como eu comentei, se você está testando diretamente na API a imagem gerada pelo seu método e lá funciona, o problema não é com ele, mas sim no envio dela. E esse é outro código.

Comment: Editei o tópico com o método de envio para o Azure.

Comment: o stream content não deveria ser Json? você já simulou um envio via postman?

Comment: Só se eu mandasse a imagem online, ai eu enviaria como Json, com o link dentro do content, mas como precisei flipar a imagem, ela está apenas local. Não testei no Postman. Vou testar e trago um retorno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente a API de exemplo do Azure é outra, no caso a Recognition Text. Peguei como "solução" [este tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924693/azure-cognitive-services-ocr-giving-differing-results-how-to-remedy). Por mais que não era o que eu procurava ele contorna o problema e entrega a mesma resposta do [site](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/).